# Parameter is null while it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am running to a somewhat weird bug in this very early morning.
The error is simple

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'FirstDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GeneratePDF(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'TimeRegPlanner.Controllers.TimeRegistrationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

The controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(DateTime FirstDate, DateTime LastDate)
{
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
function CreatePDF() {
    var xyz = document.getElementById("regDate").valueAsDate
   // var ShopDocCode = document.getElementById("werkkaart").value

    var first = xyz.getDate() - xyz.getDay() + 1;
    var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

    var firstday = new Date(xyz.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
    var lastday = new Date(xyz.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
    alert(firstday);
    alert(lastday);
    var x = document.getElementById("checkBox").checked;
    if (x === true) {
        window.location = appPath + "/TimeRegistration/GeneratePDF?FirstDate=" + firstday + "&LastDate=" + lastday;
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#dialog-Confirm").modal("hide");
    }, 3000);

}
```

when I debug and console.log the firstday and the lastday I can see they have proper values:

> firstday: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 00:00:00 GMT lastday: Sun, 30 Jun 2019
>   00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from me never having seen valueAsDate before, I would certainly encode the dates and remove whitespace in the path

```
window.location = appPath + "/TimeRegistration/GeneratePDF"+
  "?FirstDate=" + encodeURIComponent(firstday) + 
  "&LastDate="  + encodeURIComponent(lastday);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change to `ActionResult GeneratePDF(DateTime? FirstDate, DateTime? LastDate)` for preventing case `FirstDate` and `LastDate` can not cast correct to `DateTime` type

also in your JS file you should use if you dont want to use `DateTime?`

```
var firstday = new Date(xyz.setDate(first)).toISOString();
var lastday = new Date(xyz.setDate(last)).toISOString();
```

With UTC string, it can not cast to `DateTime`